# Adb and Android Studio not detecting YUPHORIA

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have just bought an Yuphoria. But adb can't detect it. I have tried drivers from different vendors but they are of no use. Now my Android Studio can't detect my Yuphoria. I have searched in internet and a lot of people have this issue. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the adb drivers but again no use. Does this mean that there is a problem with my device? What should I do? Earlier I used REDMI 1s and there was no problem with Android Studio.
In my case in device manager it shows Android Composite ADB Interface.
I saw a video on youtube and On that guy's computer it was showing something starting with YU. Please tell me what to do? And is my device ok?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of search finally I found this solution on Yu's forum answered by DoomLord and it worked..
Basically I had to add yuphoria's device id to the adb_usb.ini file..

Open windows command prompt (Windows Key + R)
Ènter: %HOMEPATH%.android
and then press OK
This will open the hidden .android folder within Home Folder of the current user.
There you will see a file called: adb_usb.ini
Edit the file using Notepad or Editplus/Notepad+
Just add the text: 0x2a96
without pressing any additional enter key/new line characters, save the file

now go to command prompt and restart adb:
adb kill-server
adb devices

Now the device will start showing up!

Answer (score 2):

For MAC users

cd ~/.android/

cat >> adb_usb.ini
0x2a96

ctrl-d // Save file

adb kill-server
adb start-server

Comment: Even after followed above steps, still it not shown up in devices list.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the adb_usb.ini was not there so I created one myself

1. Open C:\Users\.android
2. Create a new file called adb_usb.ini

[image]

3. Enter 0x2a96 and save the file

[image]

Open CMD or terminal if using Mac

```
> adb kill-server

> adb start-server

> adb devices
```

[image]